# Grid Pager not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

Why does my grid pager appear like this:

[image]

It should appear like:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"  GridLines="None"
         PageSize='<%# int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gvPageSize"].ToString()) %>'
         Width="100%" OnRowCreated="grid_RowCreated" CssClass="mGrid"
         PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="true"
 OnPageIndexChanging="grid_PageIndexChanging">
```

and css :

```
.mGrid {   
width: 100%;   
background-color: #fff;   
margin: 5px 0 10px 0;   
border: solid 1px #525252;   
border-collapse:collapse;}   
.mGrid td {   
padding: 2px;   
border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;   
color: #717171;} 
.mGrid th {   
padding: 4px 2px;   
color: #fff;   
background: #424242 url(grd_head.png) repeat-x top;   
border-left: solid 1px #525252;   
font-size: 0.9em;}
.mGrid .alt { background: #fcfcfc url(grd_alt.png) repeat-x top; }  
.mGrid .pgr { background: #424242 url(grd_pgr.png) repeat-x top;}
mGrid .pgr table { margin: 5px 0;}
.mGrid .pgr td {   
border-width: 0;   
padding: 0 6px;   
border-left: solid 1px #666;   
font-weight: bold;   
color: #fff;   
line-height: 12px;} 
.mGrid .pgr a { color: #666; text-decoration: none;}
.mGrid .pgr a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: Where is the question/issue? Yes, there are some differences in the first and second image, but which ones are your concern? The data, the width, the links below? All of them?

Comment: need a event for `PageIndexChanging`

Comment: i ask about pager style. background pager and the expanding of numbers

Comment: grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; BindData();

Answer (score 0):

Of the css that is applied to the pager, the ones marked in bold below like the margin and the padding are probably the key culprits in this case.

.mGrid .pgr table { **margin: 5px** 0;}

.mGrid .pgr td {   ...... **padding: 0 6px;** ......

You should try inspecting the css in some DOM Inspector like the Chrome Developer Tools / Firebug and tweak it till you get it to be the way you would like it to be